# Need help with lighting and materials

Tags: materials, lighting

[image]

Recently started using blender, so I am relatively new. I have also watched few blender tutorials and became interested in low poly.

The first picture in the collage is a low poly render I found online while looking for ideas and decided to make my own little low poly forest scene (second picture).

Obviously, I am having troubles with the lighting of my scene, and, the materials for the grass/land, the mountains in the back, and the water.

The grass in my render looks very fake and does not go well with the trees and water. The same goes for the mountains. As for the water, I wish to make it look similar to the water in the first render. I have used color ramps for all the materials. (For water, it is a combination of blue and green, yet there is mostly blue).

I would greatly appreciate it if someone helps me out. This has been bothering me for a few days now, and I really wish to learn advanced concepts from blender.

Edit: Added pictures for the new render and the materials for Mountains, Land and Water.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Howdy Eat the Carrot, welcome to bse. Suggest being more specific.  For example _"how do I set up this water material"_.  (or background, or lighting can be new qs)  What renderer you are using.   Add a screenshot of your material setup or a blend file.  etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going in the right direction:

The upper image has:

- better composition and general concept
- much more details (that make water reflections much more interesting)
- better focal point (the animal and the tree in the water)
- some mist effect for fake volumetric lighting (I think it's been used the z-pass to fade far objects to white)
- a gradient for the sky
- A vignette effect (darker borders, post prod or compositor effect)

This is the change you can obtain by only implementing a vignette and some curve adjustements in post production:

[image]

So, keep on modelling, add details, work on the general idea, the composition, the art, without worrying too much about materials and lighintg, that will be easier when the goals of the image will be better definied.

Comment: josh sanfelici, thank you for replying honey. Is the volumetric lighting the same option available under the World properties? Also, any idea as to why the water in my render picks only blue when rendering (I have also used a greenish shade in the material of the water).

Comment: Hi, as BatFINGER said, for this specific questions you should upload your file or, at least, show your materials windows. By now I don't even know if you're using BI or cycles, I cannot guess anything.

Comment: josh sanfelici, I attached the materials for the Mountains, Land and Water. Also, I modified my previous scene a bit.

Comment: OK, the main problem is that the random node output gives a single value, which is different for every instance of the object: if you have one piece of water only, it will generate a single color, with no variations. if you want some variations between green and blue use a color mix RGB node, and drive its FAC input with a texture (maybe start with a Wave procedural one). Enable the Node Wrangler addon and Shift Ctrl left click on a node to check its outputs. If you use an image texture set the texture coordinates to generated or unwrap the mesh.

Comment: josh sanfelici, thank you dear buns. I will try it out (: